# Understanding Memory Pools

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, memory-management, memory-pool

To my understanding, a memory pool is a block, or multiple blocks of memory allocate on the stack before runtime.
By contrast, to my understanding, dynamic memory is requested from the operating system and then allocated on the heap during run time.

**// EDIT //**

- **Memory pools are evidently *not necessarily* allocated on the stack ie. a memory pool can be used with dynamic memory.**
- **Non dynamic memory is evidently *also* not necessarily allocated on the stack, as per the answer to this question.**
- **The topics of *'dynamic vs. static memory'* and *'memory pools'* are thus not really related although the answer is still relevant.**

From what I can tell, the purpose of a memory pool is to provide manual management of RAM, where the memory must be tracked and reused by the programmer.

This is theoretically advantageous for performance for a number of reasons:

1. Dynamic memory becomes fragmented over time
2. The CPU can parse static blocks of memory faster than dynamic blocks
3. When the programmer has control over memory, they can choose to free and rebuild data when it is best to do so, according the the specific program.

4. When multithreading, separate pools allow separate threads to operate independently without waiting for the shared heap (Davislor)

Is my understanding of memory pools correct? If so, why does it seem like memory pools are not used very often?

Comment: One reason you might want separate memory pools is if you have several threads allocating and deallocating memory simultaneously. If they all use the same heap, they have to wait for the other threads to finish modifying the heap before they can proceed. If each thread has its own memory pool, it can use it without any kind of locking or waiting.

Comment: "The CPU can parse static blocks of memory..." - This is entirely _not_ how CPU's work. In fact, a typical CPU has no idea what types of memory exist in a program - they don't even know the language a program was written in!

Comment: @davislor That's a good point also, I'll edit it in to the question later.

Comment: @msalters Perhaps I should change the word 'parse' to 'access'. What I was told is that the CPU can actually loop through static memory faster. Perhaps because it is packed tighter/more likely aligned and thus has fewer cache misses?

Comment: @davislor Question edited, added the bit about threads

Comment: @bigcodeszzer: That's more a locality of reference thing, not directly related to the type of memory.

Comment: Another way in which systems often use separate memory pools is allocating small blocks of memory from a classical heap, but handling large memory allocations by mapping hardware pages into the address space.  This can perform better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**It seems this question is thwart with [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and [premature optimisation](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil).**

You should focus on writing **legible** code, then using a profiler to perform optimisations *if necessary*.

> Is my understanding of memory pools correct?

Not quite.

> ... on the stack ...
>
> ... on the heap ...

Storage duration is orthogonal to the concept of pools; **pools can be allocated to have *any* of the four storage durations** (they are: static, thread, automatic and dynamic storage duration).

The C++ standard doesn't require that *any* of these go into a *stack* or a *heap*; it might be useful to think of all of them as though they go into the same place... after all, **they all (commonly) go onto silicon chips**!

> ... allocate ... before runtime ...

What matters is that the allocation of multiple objects occurs *before* (or at least less often than) those objects are first used; this saves having to allocate each object separately. I assume this is what you meant by "before *runtime*". When choosing the size of the allocation, the closer you get to the total number of objects required at any given time the less waste from excessive allocation and the less waste from excessive resizing.

If your OS isn't prehistoric, however, the advantages of pools will quickly diminish. You'd probably see this if you used a profiler *before and after* conducting your optimisation!

> 1. Dynamic memory becomes fragmented over time

This may be true for a naive operating system such as Windows 1.0. However, in this day and age objects with allocated storage duration are commonly stored in *virtual memory*, which periodically gets written to, and read back from disk (this is called *paging*). As a consequence, fragmented memory can be defragmented and objects, functions and methods that are more commonly used might even end up being united into common *pages*.

That is, *paging* forms an implicit *pool* (and *cache prediction*) for you!

> The CPU can parse static blocks of memory faster than dynamic blocks

While objects allocated with static storage duration commonly are located *on the stack*, that's not mandated by the C++ standard. It's entirely possible that a C++ implementation may exist where-by *static blocks of memory* are allocated *on the heap*, instead.

**A cache hit on a dynamic object will be just as fast as a cache hit on a static object.** It just so happens that the *stack* is commonly kept in cache; you should try programming *without the stack* some time, and you might find that the cache has more room for *the heap*!

BEFORE you optimise you should ALWAYS **use a profiler to measure the most significant bottleneck!** Then you should perform the optimisation, and then **run the profiler again to make sure the optimisation was a success!**

This is not a machine-independent process! You need to optimise *per-implementation*! **An optimisation for *one implementation* is likely a *pessimisation* for another.**

> If so, why does it seem like memory pools are not used very often?

The virtual memory abstraction described above, in conjunction with *eliminating guess-work using cache profilers* virtually eliminates the usefulness of *pools* in all but the least-informed (i.e. **use a profiler**) scenarios.

Comment: Made some very good points. Question edited, answer accepted.

Answer (score 2):

A customized allocator can help performance since the default allocator is optimized for a specific use case, which is infrequently allocating large chunks of memory.

But let's say for example in a simulator or game, you may have a lot of stuff happening in one frame, allocating and freeing memory very frequently. In this case the default allocator is not as good.

A simple solution can be allocating a block of memory for all the throwaway stuff happening during a frame. This block of memory can be overwritten over and over again, and the deletion can be deferred to a later time. e.g: end of a game level or whatever.

Answer (score 2):

Memory pools are used to implement  custom allocators.

One commonly used is a linear allocator. It only keeps a pointer seperating allocated/free memory. Allocating with it is just a matter of incrementing the pointer by the N bytes requested, and returning it's previous value. And deallocation is done by resetting the pointer to the start of the pool.